# Фильтрафия массива js

Tags: javascript, массивы, filter

Нужно сравнить два массива и вернуть allItems с объектами, которые содержат значение из selectedItems

```
    selectedItems ['Январь', 'Март']
allItems: [
{
id:19
names: {
en:null
ru:"Январь"}
},
{
id:20
names: {
en:null
ru:"Февраль"},
},
{
id:21
names: {
en:null
ru:"Март"},
]
```

Comment: и `Array.filter()` вам не помог?

Answer (score 1):

`allItems.filter(item => selectedItems.includes(item.names.ru))` // Вернет новый массив совпавших объектов.

Answer (score 0):

Можно и по другому отфильтровать, через reduce

```js
let selectedItems  = ['Январь', 'Март'];
let allItems = [{
      id:19, 
      names: { en:null, ru:"Январь"}
    },
    {
      id:20, 
      names: { en:null, ru:"Февраль"}
    },
    {
      id:21,
      names: { en:null, ru:"Март"}
    }
];
    
let result = allItems.reduce( (acc, item) => (selectedItems.includes(item.names.ru) && acc.push(item), acc) , []);  
 
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: А можете объяснить, почему includes(item.names.ru)?

Comment: @humster_spb Да конечно что вам не понятно?

Comment: Непонятно, почему заранее выбран именно этот критерий для фильтрации?

Comment: @humster_spb Это следует из вопроса. (Нужно сравнить два массива и вернуть allItems с объектами, которые содержат значение из selectedItems)

Comment: Не следует. В вопросе требуется сравнить два массива и найти нечто общее. А Вы (как и @Rynay) просто подогнали решение под ответ, который в _данном конкретном случае_ очевиден и без всяких фильтров )) Но если массивы будут другие - сложнее, больше? По мне так нужен какой-то алгоритм прохода по всем свойствам объектов в allItems, а не только .names.ru